# Using jQuery waitForImages to wait til 50% of images are loaded then call success function

Tags: jquery, waitforimages

I would like to use the great jQuery waitForImages plugin (https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) on a slider I have in my site - it has 75 images within it - so its a bit large to load all in one go... What I would like to do is use waitForImages to show a loading DIV until lets say 50% of the images are loaded in - at that point call the success function and do my other stuff...

Anyone any ideas on how to do this?

https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

I have it working nicely on my slider waiting for 100% of the images to load but that takes too long... so want to load in a percentage and then call the success function to initiate the slider etc.

Current working code to wait for 100% of images to load in is

```
$.ajax({
cache: false,
url: 'slides.html',
success: function(data) {

     $('.bxslider').html(data).hide().waitForImages(function() {

// do stuff here like load the slider!

});

} 
});
```

I am getting close - have got this working on new load of the images with the code below - issue is, that when you view the page again with the images already loaded in - it never calls the success (halfDone) function... any ideas?

```
var halfDoneFlag = false;

function halfDone() {

console.log("10% of images are loaded, crack on!");

}


$('.bxslider').load("slides.html", function(){

alert("slide code are loaded in");


$('.bxslider').waitForImages($.noop,function(loaded, count){

    if (!halfDoneFlag && loaded > count/10) {
        halfDoneFlag = true;
        halfDone();
    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the progress callback to execute your own success callback function when half of them are done.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function halfDone() {
        console.log("Half of them are done!");
    }
    var halfDoneFlag = false;
    $(theImages).waitForImages(function(){
        // fallback just in case it never reaches half?
        if (!halfDoneFlag) {
            halfDoneFlag = true;
            halfDone();
        }
    }, function(loaded, count){
        if (!halfDoneFlag && loaded > count/2) {
            halfDoneFlag = true;
            halfDone();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - will give that a go tomorrow morning and let you know if it works

Comment: I am getting this to work when loading images for the first time - but when checking for images loaded on a page refresh once all the images are loaded in - the success function never gets called... any ideas??

Comment: Does adding a success callback help?

Comment: Doesn't appear to help no... if you take a look at my editted original comment above you will see the code which works well on initial load - but on refreshing the page once the images are loaded in - following the ajax call to load the slides.html nothing else happens...

Comment: you don't get the alert either?

Comment: In my code you mean? yeh I get the "alert("slide code are loaded in");" alert - but if I add an alert inside the $('.bxslider').waitForImages($.noop,function(loaded, count){ function i dont get it - even though all the images are loaded - I can see they are in Firebug console...

Comment: Shows me the Ajax load of slides.html is working - but the waitForImages bits dont seem to when the images are already loaded...

Comment: Sounds to me like the plugin is ignoring images that are already loaded... i've never used the plugin, so i don't know if that's intended behavior.

Comment: That's exactly what it does. https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages/blob/master/src/jquery.waitforimages.js#L67 however, the success callback should always be called, so my update should fix that issue.

Comment: OK thanks Kevin, any chance you could adapt your answer to get the theory to work inside my Ajax load call success? I appreciate it should work as you have outlined it - but in my use case it currently is not which is frustrating :)

Comment: I did... I added a success callback.

Comment: HOLD ON! doh! I had a missing fullstop on my element selector in the code... all seems spot on using your answer wrapped into my Ajax load case...

Comment: Kevin you are a legend! Thanks for your continued help here... Damn missing fullstop!

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but... what is a fullstop? Ah, a period. :)

Comment: :) you say tomato - I say tomato... USA vs UK :)

Answer (score 0):

The [code I wrote on GitHub](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages/issues/37#issuecomment-41106641) should achieve this...

```
$("#container")
  .waitForImages({ 
      each: function( loaded, count ) { 
            if (loaded / count > .5) {
                  // 50% have loaded.
            }
       } 
  });
```

Comment: When I used your code example it seemed to call the function on 50% load of EACH Image. I wanted 50% of ALL images loaded :)

Comment: @dubbs That's not true.