# Wait until 50% loaded

Tags: waitforimages

Trying to run a success function at 50% progress using the waitforimages plugin.
https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

I tried the accepted answer at [Using jQuery waitForImages to wait til 50% of images are loaded then call success function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229783/using-jquery-waitforimages-to-wait-til-50-of-images-are-loaded-then-call-succes) and had no luck.  Maybe something's changed with the plugin since then, but it just triggers the success function immediately.

Has anyone had any luck getting a function to run at 50% of images loaded?

Thanks!  Rich

Element needing it

```
<section id="s-hero-prim">
<div id="loading"><i class="animated fadeIn fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>
<div class="slides">
    <figure class="img hero" style="background-image: url(/admin/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Dancing-Bhutan-1_2560x1440_acf_cropped.jpg);"></figure>
    <figure class="img hero" style="background-image: url(/admin/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/DSC_0587_2560x1440_acf_cropped.jpg);"></figure>
    <figure class="img hero" style="background-image: url(/admin/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Colombia-red-house-blue-door-2-1_2560x1440_acf_cropped-2.jpg);"></figure>
    <figure class="img hero" style="background-image: url(/admin/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/South-Africa-Dune_2560x1440_acf_cropped.jpg);"></figure>
    <figure class="img hero" style="background-image: url(/admin/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Australia-opera-1-3_2560x1440_acf_cropped.jpg);"></figure>
    <figure class="img hero" style="background-image: url(/admin/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Burma-cover-correction-web_2560x1440_acf_cropped.png);"></figure>
    <figure class="img hero" style="background-image: url(/admin/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Uniquely-Europe_2560x1440_acf_cropped.png);"></figure>
</div>
```

and the code i've tried

```
function startSlideshow() {
    $('#s-hero-prim').addClass('loaded');
}
var halfDoneFlag = false;
$('#s-hero-prim').waitForImages(function(){
    // fallback just in case it never reaches half
    if (!halfDoneFlag) {
        halfDoneFlag = true;
        startSlideshow();
    }
}, function(loaded, count){
    if (!halfDoneFlag && loaded > count/2) {
        halfDoneFlag = true;
        startSlideshow();
    }
});
```

Comment: Add your code here too.

Comment: Thanks, just updated post